# Распарсить строку с помощью preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеются такие данные:

```
$pattern = "/статьи/администрирование/([0-9])+/([0-9])+/";
$string  = "/статьи/администрирование/129/123/";
```

Мне нужен какой-то механизм, который мог бы выудить из `$string` числа 129 и 123, при чем `$pattern` может меняться, например, если он будет таким:

```
  $pattern = "/статьи/администрирование/([0-9])+/";
```

а  `$string` такой:

```
 $string  = "/статьи/администрирование/129/";
```

то вытянуть нужно будет число 129.

Я сделал так:

```
if(preg_match("~$pattern ~", $string ,$matches)){
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($matches);
                echo "</pre>";
}
```

Но получил в массиве `$matches` не то что нужно, а именно:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /статьи/администрирование/129/123/
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 3
)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в массиве было это:

Array
    (
        [0] => /статьи/администрирование/129/123/
        [1] => 129
        [2] => 123
    )

Comment: `+` внутрь круглых скобок внесите

Comment: ^ и пробел перед тильдой уберите. и все заработает

Comment: заменить `([0-9])+` на `(\d+)` и убрать пробел после переменной шаблона в `"~$pattern ~"`

Comment: Всем спасибо)) Напишите в ответы, отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Кроме замечаний в комментариях, вам надо заменить ограничители в шаблоне *(чтоб не экранировать слеши)*

```
$string  = '/статьи/администрирование/129/123/';
$pattern = '~/статьи/администрирование/(\d+)/(\d+)/~';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Данная регулярка будет отлично работать и без флага **u** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa16da4443bde70f1dd959d16742c4b4192ad9ab так как в ней нет символьных классов с многобайтовыми символами, а подстрока `/статьи/администрирование/` определяется однозначно в одной и той же кодировке ;)

Comment: @Visman действительно - сейчас подправлю ответ.